# ¿Como confirmar antes de eliminar un registro con PHP y AlertifyJS?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

Tengo una duda con la confirmación antes de eliminar un registro de mi Base de datos, para esto estoy utilizando PHP y la librería de AlertifyJS, en mi estructura HTML tengo un enlace mediante el cual envío por método GET el id de la persona a eliminar, en este mismo enlace tengo una clase llamada **elimina** la cual utilizo en JQuery para disparar la función que contiene el **alertify.confirm**, cabe mencionar que si me elimina a la persona pero el problema es que me manda la confirmación pero no me deja decidir si quiero o no eliminar al usuario.

```
<a href="becarios.php?becarioid=<?php echo $registro['id_becario'];?>" class="enlace-table elimina" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Eliminar Becario" alt="Eliminar Becario">
    <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
</a>
```

código JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

   $('.elimina').on('click', function() {
       validaBaja();
   });
});
 function validaBaja() {
       alertify.confirm("Deseas eliminar al usuario",
            function(){
               alertify.success('Eliminado');
       },
       function(){
           alertify.error('Cancelado');
       }
      );
}
```

Código PHP

```
$delBecario = verificaId($_GET['becarioid']);

if (!empty($delBecario)) 
{
   $sql_del_becario = "DELETE FROM becarios WHERE id_becario='$delBecario'";
   $elimina = eliminaRegistro($sql_del_becario, $conecta);
   if ($elimina !== false) 
   {
      header('Location:becarios.php');
   }
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, no deberías eliminar un registro mediante un `GET`, usaría un `POST` (o un `DELETE` si es una Api REST). Luego, utilizaría una función en JS que elimine el registro mediante Ajax.

Crearía un botón que tenga un atributo `data` con el id a eliminar.

```
<button type="button" class="elimina" data-becarioId="<?php echo $registro['id_becario']; ?>">Eliminar</button>
```

Luego el JS, en el evento click, obtenes el id que está asociado al botón mediante el atributo `data`. Lo pasas por parámetro a la función que elimina.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.elimina').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('becarioId');
    eliminar(id);
  });

  var eliminar = function(id) {
    alertify.confirm("Deseas eliminar al usuario", function() {

      // confirma eliminar
      $.post('tu_url_para_eliminar.php', { becarioId: id }, function(data) {
        // se eliminó correctamente
        alertify.success('Usuario eliminado');
      }).fail(function() {
        // ocurrió un error
        alertify.error('Error al eliminar usuario');
      });

    });
  }

});
```

Método [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType)

Método [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (versión completa de `$.post()` o `$.get()`)

Answer (score 2):

Saludos te dejo el codigo:

```
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.1/build/css/alertify.min.css"/>
<form action="" onsubmit="return false" name="miFormulario">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Grabar Datos">
</form>
<script>
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){

    alertify.confirm('Confirm Title', 'Confirm Message',
    function(){
    //submit
    document.miFormulario.submit();
    alertify.success('Ok') 
    },
    function(){ 
    alertify.error('Cancel')

    });
});


</script>
```

**Explicacion**, dentro del form:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return false" name="miFormulario">
```

detengo el submit para controlarlo por javascript, adicional se asigna un name al form que sirva para una vez confirmada la accion envio el form o hago el submit.

```
//submit
document.miFormulario.submit();
```

con ese codigo lo que hago una vez confirmada la accion del alert envio el form o forzo el submit.

```
'Confirm Title', 'Confirm Message',
```

esa parte sirve para poner el titulo del alert y tu mensaje:
[image: resultado]

Espero te sirva, te dejo el link de la documentacion oficial para mayor informacion.
[Documentacion-Confirm](https://alertifyjs.com/confirm.html)